# ProgressBar display with some delay in on click of option menu

Tags: android, android-progressbar, optionmenu

I am facing the issue with displaying progressbar onItem selected in option menu.
My code is here:

```
case R.id.mnuLogout:

                showDialog(Constants.PROGRESS_DIALOG);
                closeOptionsMenu(); 

                             if(MyApp.IsLoggedOut())
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.LOGOUT);
                 else
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.ERROR_MSG);
```

Progressbar is displayed after completion of IsLogged method.

Comment: Not sure what happen... but... why are you invoking methods of your `AsyncTask` from there? You shouldn't be doing that... you should send those empty messages from within your `AsyncTask` not from your `onOptionsMenuItemClick`.

Comment: that's true, but the Async Task is a different class, not a part of this class. Also i have done the with simple method calling also(without Async task), then also it's delayed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `get()` right after the `AsyncTask` as executed and lose asynchronous behavior because this method waits until task is finished. You should add all the code in try/catch block to `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method and also dismiss the dialog from this method.

```
void doLogout() {
    new LogoutTask().execute();
}

void dispatchLogoutFinished() {
    dismissDialog(Constants.PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    if (MyApp.IsLoggedOut()) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}

private class LogoutTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        TheActivity.this.showDialog(Constants.PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        TheActivity.this.dispatchLogoutFinished();
    }
}
```

And I don't think you need to send messages to the handler. The `dispatchLogoutFinished()` is executed on the UI thread, so there's no need for synchronization.

Comment: If i will not wait for response it will handler before completion the task. Also, the Aysnc task is a separate class so can not open/dismiss dialog:(

Comment: If you wait for the `AsyncTask` to complete in your UI thread, using `AsyncTask` becomes unnecessary complication and makes no sense. It's called `AsyncTask` because it's asynchronous and that's why it notifies UI thread about finishing with a special method. If `AsyncTask` is a non-static nested class then it contains a reference to an outer class. Otherwise you can pass an `Activity` to a constructor of the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I have removed the async task but same issue still exist :(

Comment: No, you didn't get it. You NEED `AsyncTask` but you also need to use it correctly. This means you have to perform all the stuff in the `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method and do not call the `AsyncTask.get()` method.

Comment: I have done this also, but you know it seems that option menu issue :(